# MX Notify Control issues with EE 2.9

Tags: mx-notify

I just updated my site to EE 2.9 from EE 2.6.1. I'm using MX Notify Control v. 2.4.6 along with the fieldtype MX Delegate Email to send out emails after Zoo Visitor updates. The field type is causing problems throughout the site now. I cannot access any of the Channel Fields in the EE CP, nor access any of the entries that use MX Delegate Email.

Since I have hundreds of Zoo Visitor entries that include a field for MX Delegate email, I was afraid to just remove the field to see if that fixes it.

The error I am getting is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Fieldtype::EE_Fieldtype() in /home2/account/system/expressionengine/third_party/mx_delegate_email/ft.mx_delegate_email.php on line 16
```

I'm hoping that Max Lazar or someone will give me a suggestion of what to do.

---

UPDATE: I ended up doing a search for the Fatal error I mentioned above, and found a hack that worked here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/simple-s3-uploader/viewthread/12869

In the MX Delegate Email plugin code, I changed

```
parent::EE_Fieldtype();
```

to

```
parent::__construct();
```

It fixed the problems I mentioned above plus a few others I didn't know were related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compatibility bug was fixed 3 month ago and available [in last version](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-notify-control)